# How to reload NetworkManager after installing NetworkManager-wifi

Tags: centos, wifi, networkmanager

I have a wireless card installed and `nmcli` reports that it is "unmanaged" with text in red that a "plugin is missing".

Googling around led me to identify that I need to install the requisite "NetworkManager-wifi" package. After installation over a wired connection, the red message about the plugin being missing did not go away until after a reboot, after which the device became managed and automatically connected to a network I had setup through `nmtui`.

My question is, how can I reload NetworkManager to recognize the plugin needed for the wifi to work without a reboot?

I tried:

```
$ service network reload
```

This did not have any affect.

Comment: `network` != `NetworkManager`

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that, the problem comes back after the first reboot succeeded in fixing it?

Comment: The problem goes away after installing this package and rebooting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relading a device plugin (as provided by NetworkManager-wifi) is not supported. You need to restart NetworkManager via `systemctl restart NetworkManager` (or whatever service manager/init you use).

It's not supported because it's high effort and not easily possible. That is because the plugin is a shared library, and while it could be loaded on demand, it cannot be unloaded or updated without restart. Since restart anyway is required to work well, that is the suggested way for installing a device plugin.

Note that a restart of the NetworkManager service is usually not required, for example when doing changes to the networking configuration. This is one of the exceptions.

And yes, Ipor is right: `network.service` != `network.target` != `NetworkManager.service` (in systemd).